# How to find $f^{−1}([9,0])$ and $f([1,4])$ for $f(x)=x-6\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$f$ is a the function defined by   $$\eqalign{ f\colon& \Bbb R &\rightarrow \Bbb R_+\\ 
     & x&\mapsto x-6\sqrt{x} }$$
Find  $f^{−1}([-9,0])$ and $f([1,4])$.

Comment: Your title is different than your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I think it was edited, Mr.Tim Seguine .

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$f'(x)=1-\frac3{\sqrt x}\ge0\iff x\ge 9$$
hence $f$ is decreasing on the interval $[1,4]$ so
$$f([1,4])=[f(4),f(1)]$$
and

$$f^{-1}([-9,0])=[f^{-1}(0),f^{-1}(-9)]$$
and to find $f^{-1}(-9)$ we solve for $x$ the equation
$$f(x)=-9$$

Comment: I'm sorry thank you but i just realized i made a mistake.It's -9 not 9.